# Is it possible that Allah will not ask for the account of some people on the day of judgement

Tags: day-of-judgement

Is it possible that Allah SWT will not ask for the account of some people on the day of judgement, because some people do add it to their prayers that Allah SWT should not ask for their account on the day of judgement

Answer (score 0):

Asalaam Alaikum

YES, it is possible. there are numerous authentic ahadith mentioning the people who will enter jannah without bein taken into account. such narrations are there in sunan ibn majah, sahih al-bukhari and sahih muslim. i'll mention the narration in sunan ibn majah as this hadith is more related to the part in your question where people keep asking Allah the mighty and sublime to make them among one of them. (those who will be not held accountable).

Abu Umamah Al-Bahili said:

I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: My Lord has promised me that seventy thousand of my nation will enter Paradise without being brought to account or punished. With every thousand will be (another) seventy thousand, and three handfuls of my Lord, the Glorified.

[sunan ibn majah 4286]

(this hadith is graded hasan by Darussallam)

please reffer to hadith 6472 in sahih al-bukhari and hadith 218b in sahih muslim to have more understanding of those who will enter jannah without reckoning.

may Allah the glorified and exalted grant you mercy and guide you to the straight path.

Allah knows best.